# Phpunit ignore methods in extending classes

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm running PHPUnit, and have a class with a few tests

```
class TestVideo extends BaseTest
    {
        public function setUp()
        {
             //etc...
        }

        public function testA()
        {
            .....;
        }

        public function testB()
        {
            .....;
        }
    }
```

If I extend this class, all tests will run in the derived class.

```
class TestPhoneVideo extends TestVideo
    {
       
    }
```

What if i only want `testB` to run in `TestPhoneVideo`, but not `testA`?

Comment: `BaseTest` does not come from PHPUnit. If you are using PHPUnit, then `TestVideo` should be `VideoTest` and `TestPhoneVideo` should be `PhoneVideoTest` (`Test` suffix instead of prefix).

Comment: I think you have the idea of inheritance wrong, inheriting some functionality but not others is contrary to the idea that you inherit the functionality because it is a type of the base class.

Answer (score 0):

This is how inheritance works for test case classes: if you extend `PhoneVideoTest` from `VideoTest`, then all tests from `VideoTest` are now also part of `PhoneVideoTest`.

That being said, the usual means of filtering are available. For instance, you can annotate your test(s) with `@group` and select the group of tests to (not) run with `--group` (`--exclude-group`). Or you can use `--filter`.